# How can I dynamically compose/chain multiple 'handleSubmit' methods in React Hook Form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hook-form

I have multiple useForm hooks in my form component. I want to create a method to dynamically handle one submit button for an arbitrary number of hooks. The idea is that the partial forms should be validated successively.

For an isolated scenario, this approach works:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

const MyFormComponent = () => {

   const form1 = useForm();
   const form2 = useForm();

   const onSubmitSuccess = () => {
      //some success logic
   };

   const handleMultiple = form1.handleSubmit(form2.handleSubmit(onSubmitSuccess));

   return <React.Fragment>
      {
         ...form1Fields
      }

      {
         ...form2Fields
      }

      <button onClick={handleMultiple}>submit</button>
   </React.Fragment>
}
```

Now I want to create a generic 'handleMultiple'. I tried to utilize the redux 'compose' function, but that approach just ignores the validation:

```
import { compose } from 'redux'

const getHandleMultiple = (submitFunc, ...forms) => {
   const handleMultiple = compose(
      ...forms.map(form => form.handleSubmit),
      submitFunc
   );

   return {
      handleMultiple
   }
}
```

Any ideas how to archive this? Different approaches are also appreciatied.

EDIT: I tried to wrap the compose-method in a 'useMemo' hook, as @AhmedI.Elsayed suggested, but that didn't solve the problem:

```
const useComposedFormSubmit = (submitFunc, ...forms) => {
    const handleComposedSubmit = useMemo(() => {
        
        return compose(
            ...forms.map(form => form.handleSubmit), 
            submitFunc
        )

    }, [forms, submitFunc])

    return { 
        handleComposedSubmit
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-compose-handlesubmit-yes5y9

Comment: No relation to react-hook-form, you're probably looking for composing functions, lodash has helpers for this, just copy and paste it in your code and edit it as you need, or install the library

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AhmedI.Elsayed. The problem is, the redux compose function should do the same as I understand it. The handleSubmit method of React Hook Form is a bit special though, as it conditionally executes the function passed depending on the state of the validation. That's why I asked and tagged my question accordingly, in case the problem has something to do with this behaviour. 

I'll take a look at the lodash implementation nevertheless.

Comment: I think your approach seems fine, I just saw `compose` from redux as I forgot what it does, I think your problem is that the forms are initially empty at some point during rerendering, I'll provide an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 1**: So handleSubmit gets called on your onSubmit and this gets repeated for every handleSubmit we have, this is basically as if we express it mathematically as:

```
handleSubmit2(handleSubmit1(onSubmit))(x)
```

but compose?

```
compose(...forms.map((form) => form.handleSubmit), submitFunc);
```

This is

```
handler2(handler1(submitFunc(x)))
```

and if we composed in opposite order

```
submitFunc(handler1(handler2(x)))
```

which is still not what we need. What we need to do is ignore `compose` because that's not what we need, and implement our own function.

```
const useComposedFormSubmit = (submitFunc, ...forms) => {
  return useMemo(() => {
    const fns = [...forms.map(f => f.handleSubmit)];
    return fns.reduce((p, c) => {
      return c(p);
    }, submitFunc); 
  }, [submitFunc, forms]); 
};
```

No reduce version

```
const useComposedFormSubmit = (submitFunc, ...forms) => {
  return useMemo(() => {
    const fns = [...forms.map(f => f.handleSubmit)];
    let resultFunc = submitFunc;

    for (const fn of fns) {
      resultFunc = fn(resultFunc);
    }

    return resultFunc;
  }, [submitFunc, forms]); 
};
```

---

##### OLD ANSWER, NOT WORKING BUT EXPLAINS HOW TO EXPRESS THE OP POST IN `compose`

I think the problem is due to forms being undefined at some point, not sure but you can test this one and I'm pretty sure it should work, this is a hook. Hooks should start with `use` as documented.

```
const useMultipleSubmitters = (submitFunc, ...forms) => {
   return useMemo(() => {
      return compose(...forms.map(f => form.handleSubmit), submitFunc)
    }, [forms, submitFunc])
}
```

and adjust as needed. It's the same as yours but recalculates on rerenders.

Comment: Thanks again for the input. I tried your solution (see the update if my original post). Sadly, the problem still occurs.

Comment: @TNgermany compose function works from right to left, I think the behaviour you need is left to right, which is usually called `pipe`, the rtl version is `compose`. regardless of the terminology, can you confirm that piping works ? if so, I'll edit my answer

You can get a piping implementation by searching for `left to right composition javascript` or something

Comment: @TNgermany try lodash, you have both named `flow` and `flowRight`

Comment: I tried to flip the composing, so the submitFunc should be called in the end. That still did not work. 


I created a code sandbox, in case you want to fiddle around with the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-compose-handlesubmit-yes5y9

Comment: @TNgermany thanks, this helped, I've provided the answer to your problem

Comment: Thank you so much for the time you spend on this. I can confirm that your solution works. I still try to wrap my head around your solution, the [].reduce() method makes my head spin. But I'll get it sooner or later :)

Comment: @TNgermany I've added a no reduce version